# Model form foreign key field to duration field not working

Tags: django

I have the following form where the user selects a value which corresponds to a duration field of the name value in a model called Duration.

When the form is submitted I'm getting this error

```
return (24 * 60 * 60 * delta.days + delta.seconds) * 1000000 + delta.microseconds

Attribute Error - 'str' object has no attribute days.
```

Clearly Django expects the argument to be a timedelta object when this method is called and it is getting a string instead.  Where am I at fault ?

The form :

```
class AuctionCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Auction
        fields = ['title', 'reserve']
        exclude = ('duration',)
        labels = {'reserve': _('Reserve')}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["duration_value"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Duration.objects.all(),
            empty_label=None,
            to_field_name="value",
        )
```

The view :

```
class AuctionCreate(CreateView):
    """ View function for creating an auction """
    form_class = AuctionCreateForm
    template_name = "auction/auction_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.start = timezone.now()
        duration_value = form.cleaned_data.get('duration_value')
        form.instance.duration = Duration.objects.get(value=duration_value)
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And here are the two models if it helps.

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    """ Model for an auction """
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        db_index=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    duration = models.ForeignKey(
        Duration, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True
    )
    reserve = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )
    winning_bid = models.ForeignKey(
        'Bid',
        related_name='highest_bid',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )    


class Duration(models.Model):
    """ Choice durations for auction """
    value = models.DurationField()

    def __str__(self):
        return humanfriendly.format_timespan(self.value)
```

I know there is nothing wrong with the duration objects I have.  I created them through the admin interface successfully where it provides a text field and entered a value in seconds.  Furthermore, in another part of the application, where i list the auction, i can retrieve the values and do arithmetic on them.

Full Traceback -

```
[22/Apr/2019 13:08:54] "GET /auction/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3234
Internal Server Error: /auction/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 172, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 141, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 399, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 148, in clean
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1248, in to_python
    value = self.queryset.get(**{key: value})
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1084, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 486, in as_sql
    where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 402, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 81, in as_sql
    sql, params = compiler.compile(child)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 402, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 163, in as_sql
    rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 260, in process_rhs
    return super().process_rhs(compiler, connection)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 95, in process_rhs
    return self.get_db_prep_lookup(value, connection)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 187, in get_db_prep_lookup
    [get_db_prep_value(value, connection, prepared=True)]
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1619, in get_db_prep_value
    return duration_microseconds(value)
  File "/home/ross/.local/share/virtualenvs/v4-MIvAvlKB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/duration.py", line 44, in duration_microseconds
    return (24 * 60 * 60 * delta.days + delta.seconds) * 1000000 + delta.microseconds
```

This is what the html for the select widget looks like -

```
<select name="duration_value" id="id_duration_value">
  <option value="0:05:00">5 minutes</option>

  <option value="0:10:00">10 minutes</option>

  <option value="0:20:00">20 minutes</option>

  <option value="0:40:00">40 minutes</option>

  <option value="1:00:00">1 hour</option>

  <option value="2:00:00">2 hours</option>

  <option value="4:00:00">4 hours</option>

  <option value="8:00:00">8 hours</option>

  <option value="16:00:00">16 hours</option>

  <option value="1 day, 0:00:00">1 day</option>

</select>
```

Comment: can you share the whole traceback

Comment: what is `delta` defined as?

Comment: I'll update the question for the select options it pulls from the db.  As stated in the question, they were all created through the text input field in the admin interface - i entered in an integer second value for each.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is `DurationField` works on a `timedelta` object. So you need to convert your string to `timedelta` object and then perform the lookup

```
# views.py
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_duration
class AuctionCreate(CreateView):
    """ View function for creating an auction """
    form_class = AuctionCreateForm
    template_name = "auction/auction_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.start = timezone.now()
        duration_value = form.cleaned_data.get('duration_value')
        duration_obj = parse_duration(duration_value)  # convert string to timedelta object
        form.instance.duration = Duration.objects.get(value=duration_obj)
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the problem occurs before the form is even declared valid.  I've tried overwriting the post method and changing the field to a timedelta object with the method you suggest but obviously you can't change the POST dict because it is immutable.  Besides, surely all this should be unnecessary.  Django should be taking care of this already and doing the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone...

Got it working like this for functions -

```
@login_required
def AuctionCreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.POST = request.POST.copy()
        duration_value = request.POST["duration_value"]
        duration_value = parse_duration(duration_value)
        request.POST["duration_value"] = duration_value
        print(request.POST)
        form = AuctionCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Auction.objects.create(
                title=form.cleaned_data["title"],
                valid_from=timezone.now(),
                duration=Duration.objects.get(value=duration_value),
                reserve=form.cleaned_data["reserve"],
                creator=request.user,
                winning_bid=None
            )
            return HttpResponse("Created auction")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Something went wrong")
    else:
        form = AuctionCreateForm()
        return render (
            request,
            'auction/auction_form.html',
            {
                'form': form
            }
        )
```

And like this for class based view -

```
    """ View function for creating an auction """
    form_class = AuctionCreateForm
    template_name = "auction/auction_form.html"    

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.POST = request.POST.copy()
        duration_value = request.POST["duration_value"]
        duration_value = parse_duration(duration_value)
        request.POST["duration_value"] = duration_value
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)                                                    

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.start = timezone.now()
        duration_value = form.cleaned_data.get('duration_value')
        form.instance.duration = duration_value
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```